# OCaml Error Unbound value List.unzip

Tags: ocaml

Any idea why I am getting this error:

```
utop # let (ints,strings) = List.unzip [(1,"one"); (2,"two"); (3,"three")];;
Error: Unbound value List.unzip
```

Comment: That is an example from "Real World OCaml", page 30

Comment: In Real World OCaml, they talk about how many of these kinds of functions are part of Jane Street's Core and not part of the stdlib.

Comment: We have all been there... Library shortcomings and replacements is heavily discussed right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `List.unzip` in the standard library.
I'm guessing you're looking for `List.split`:

```
# let (ints,strings) = List.split [(1,"one"); (2,"two"); (3,"three")];;
val ints : int list = [1; 2; 3]
val strings : string list = ["one"; "two"; "three"]
```

---

Note: There *is* a `List.unzip` function in OCaml-Core. If you're using it, you probably didn't open the corresponding module.

Comment: Thanks, I was not importing Core.Std. Sorry I just started learning OCaml and I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

List.unzip is provided in Base library, you need to install it.